# No suitable servers found (serverSelectionTryOnce set): [connection refused calling hello on 'mongodb:21017']

Tags: laravel, mongodb, laravel-sail

I want to use mongodb in my laravel sail project.
How can solve problem like
**No suitable servers found (`serverSelectionTryOnce` set): [connection refused calling hello on 'mongodb:21017']**

Next code return this error

```
  try {
           $l =  DB::connection('mongodb')->getMongoClient()->listDatabases();
           dd($l);

        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
```

My configuration of env

```
MONGO_DB_HOST=mongodb
MONGO_DB_PORT=21017
MONGO_DB_DATABASE=test
MONGO_DB_USERNAME=sail
MONGO_DB_PASSWORD=password
```

My docker-compose

```
    mongodb:
        image: mongo:4.4.6
        ports:
            - '${FORWARD_MONGO_DB_PORT:-27017}:27017'
        environment:
            MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: '${MONGO_DB_USERNAME}'
            MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: '${MONGO_DB_PASSWORD}'
            MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE: '${MONGO_DB_DATABASE}'
        volumes:
            - 'sail-mongodb:/data/db'
        networks:
            - sail
```

In my dockerfile with php8.2
i install mongodb exctension

```
RUN pecl install mongodb
```

I try use ping from inside **laravel.test** container to **mongodb** container
Like that `ping mongodb` and its return success, no losses data.
Also i can connect to mongo shell inside my **mongodb** container

Comment: Check docker-compose ps

Comment: docker-compose ps return 
backend-mongodb-1        "docker-entrypoint.s…"   mongodb             running             0.0.0.0:21017->27017/tcp

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I was using the wrong port 21017 instead of 27017